# How can i make my listview item editable?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

My doubt is am having one activity inside that one fragment i need to populate the listview in activity from fragment data and should be save it in sharedpreferences which i done successfully now what i want to do is when i click listitems it must go source from where data gets entered like editing the listview items how can i do this so far what i have tried is:

This is Fragment (from_data):

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by 4264 on 16-12-2015.
 */
public class NewCompetitors extends Fragment {
    CompetitorsData competitorsData;
Competitors competitors;
    Context context;

    CompetitorsView competitorsView = new CompetitorsView();
EditText editText_name,editText_website,editText_strength,editText_weakness;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_competitors_fragment, container, false);
        editText_name = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.competitors_name);
        editText_website = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.competitors_website);
        editText_strength = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.competitors_strength);
         editText_weakness = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.competitors_weakness);
        Button btn_save = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
       Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
       String yoggs=bundle.getString("yogg");
        editText_name.setText(yoggs);
editText_website.setText(yoggs);
        editText_strength.setText(yoggs);
        editText_weakness.setText(yoggs);
                btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               editTextcompetitor();
                sendData(competitorsView);
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

            }
               });
            return rootView;
    }

public void editTextcompetitor(){
    competitorsView.setCompetitor_name(editText_name.getText().toString());
    competitorsView.setCompetitor_website(editText_website.getText().toString());
    competitorsView.setCompetitor_strength(editText_strength.getText().toString());
    competitorsView.setCompetitor_weakness(editText_weakness.getText().toString());

}

    public void sendData(CompetitorsView competitorsView) {
        competitorsData.dataToCompetitorActivity(competitorsView);

   }


 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
           competitorsData = (CompetitorsData) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()+ "");
        }
    }
public interface CompetitorsData{
    void dataToCompetitorActivity(CompetitorsView competitorsView);
}
}
```

This is my activity where listview gets populated from fragment:

```
package first.service.precision.servicefirst;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Competitors extends Activity implements NewCompetitors.CompetitorsData{
ListView lv;
    String god;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    ObjectOutputStream out;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    public String yog;
   List<CompetitorsView> competitorsViews;
  public   CompetitorsListAdapter competitorsListAdapter;
    static Context contexts;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_competitors);

        contexts=this;
        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_competitors);
        competitorsViews=new ArrayList<CompetitorsView>();

      ;
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(contexts);
        Gson gsong=new Gson();
        final String yog=sharedPreferences.getString("yog","");
        Type type=new TypeToken<ArrayList<CompetitorsView>>(){}.getType();
       competitorsViews=gsong.fromJson(yog,type);
        competitorsListAdapter=new CompetitorsListAdapter(this,R.id.list_competitors,competitorsViews);
        lv.setAdapter(competitorsListAdapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             god  =String.valueOf(id);
                NewCompetitors fragment = new NewCompetitors();
                Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("yogg",god);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.competitors_frame, fragment);
                ft.commit();
            }

        });

        Button btn_competitors=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_new_competitors);
        btn_competitors.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                NewCompetitors fragment = new NewCompetitors();
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.add(R.id.competitors_frame, fragment);
                ft.addToBackStack(null);
                ft.commit();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        contexts=this;
        SharedPreferences sharedpref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(contexts);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedpref.edit();
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        String god=gson.toJson(competitorsViews);
        editor.putString("yog",god);
        editor.commit();
        super.onStop();
    }






    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

  /*  public static CompetitorsView get_User_From_Shared_Prefs(Context context)
    {



    }*/

    @Override
    public void dataToCompetitorActivity(CompetitorsView competitorsView)
    {
        competitorsViews.add(competitorsView);
        competitorsListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

how can my listview item editable?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get at? If you want to edit items within a `ListView`, I suggest to create a separate Activity to handle the selected content rather than within the same controller.

Comment: see this https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/

Comment: am populating listivew in activity from fragment data which i navigate the data through interface when i click listivew items it must go to the source fragment where it comes from

Comment: am not looking for this@Lakhan what i need is it should go to concern fragment